# WSO2 IoT 3.1.0 failed to retreive oauth token using jwt error

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot, wso2-identity-server

I am installing WSO2 IOT Server 3.1.0 on a server. I just want to run it with default basic configurations. After Uploading to my server, I configured it to run with the IP using the script as mentioned in this [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Configuring+the+IP+or+Hostname).

After running the script, I ran the broker and the iotserver profiles. I am able to log in the API store and publisher but when I tries to log in the devicemgt web console. I am getting the following error.

**Error Snapshot:**
[image]

**Exception In Logs:**

```
An exception thrown when executing the script '/app/modules/login.js'. {auth-module}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-12-04 00:32:43,944] ERROR {auth-module} -  org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.integration.client.exception.APIMClientOAuthException: failed to retrieve oauth token using jwt {auth-module}
org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.integration.client.exception.APIMClientOAuthException: failed to retrieve oauth token using jwt (/devicemgt/app/modules/login.js#31)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:85)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.app.modules.c3._c_anonymous_2(/devicemgt/app/modules/login.js:31)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.app.modules.c3.call(/devicemgt/app/modules/login.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.lib.modules.auth.c0._c_executeScript_10(/devicemgt/lib/modules/auth/auth.js:234)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.lib.modules.auth.c0.call(/devicemgt/lib/modules/auth/auth.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.lib.modules.auth.c0._c_handleEvent_11(/devicemgt/lib/modules/auth/auth.js:259)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.lib.modules.auth.c0.call(/devicemgt/lib/modules/auth/auth.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.lib.modules.auth.c0._c_anonymous_20(/devicemgt/lib/modules/auth/auth.js:547)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.lib.modules.auth.c0.call(/devicemgt/lib/modules/auth/auth.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.lib.modules.auth.c2._c_anonymous_1(/devicemgt/lib/modules/auth/acs.jag:34)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.lib.modules.auth.c2.call(/devicemgt/lib/modules/auth/acs.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.lib.modules.auth.c2._c_script_0(/devicemgt/lib/modules/auth/acs.jag:22)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.lib.modules.auth.c2.call(/devicemgt/lib/modules/auth/acs.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.lib.modules.auth.c2.call(/devicemgt/lib/modules/auth/acs.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.lib.modules.auth.c2.exec(/devicemgt/lib/modules/auth/acs.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.authenticator.framework.WebappAuthenticationValve.invoke(WebappAuthenticationValve.java:45)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1760)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1719)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.integration.client.exception.APIMClientOAuthException: failed to retrieve oauth token using jwt
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.integration.client.OAuthRequestInterceptor.apply(OAuthRequestInterceptor.java:118)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.targetRequest(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:158)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:88)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.tiersTierLevelTierNameGet(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.application.extension.APIManagementProviderServiceImpl.isTierLoaded(APIManagementProviderServiceImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.jwt.client.extension.exception.JWTClientException: Error when parsing the response <am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>101500</am:code><am:type>Status report</am:type><am:message>Runtime Error</am:message><am:description>Error in Sender</am:description></am:fault>
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.jwt.client.extension.JWTClient.getTokenInfo(JWTClient.java:169)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.jwt.client.extension.JWTClient.getAccessToken(JWTClient.java:79)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.integration.client.OAuthRequestInterceptor.apply(OAuthRequestInterceptor.java:99)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: Unexpected character (<) at position 0.
    at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.jwt.client.extension.JWTClient.getTokenInfo(JWTClient.java:153)
    ... 88 more
```

Can anybody help pointing out what is going wrong and what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same IP as the one you entered when asked for the common name when running the change IP script, to access the server?

Appreciate if you could add here the entire log for server startup. That way we would be able to figure out what exactly is causing the problem.